# javascript if a html element text equal with 0, addClass to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element that contains the discount of a product

```html
<div class="discount_discountAmount">
    <div id="mydiscouttext" class="discouttext">0
        <span class="price_percent">%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want, if the element with id="mydiscouttext" equal to 0, addClass "hide".

I am looking for a solution with javascript.

Any idea?

Comment: Get the element, get its first child node, compare …?

Comment: Read about [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: not answer but just sugestion if you wnat to write codes avilable in multiply cultures. you need to keep your integer and your % perchant in the same string. because in different cultures % can be at the begining or can be at the end of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes to:

```
<div class="discount_discountAmount">
    <div id="mydiscouttext" class="discouttext">
        <span class="value_percent">0</span>
        <span class="price_percent">%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var discouttext = $('#mydiscouttext span:first-child').html();
    if(discouttext === '0')
        $('.discount_discountAmount').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar for another person, where I the table row had to be highlighted in the case of value in a cell being <=5. Please see if this helps you: https://codepen.io/nitinsuri/pen/WoqLzX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table#book-list").find("td").each(function(){
    var quantity = parseInt($.trim($(this).text()));
    if(quantity <= 5){
      $(this).parent("tr").addClass("low-quantity");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!parseInt(document.querySelector("#mydiscouttext").innerText)){
    document.querySelector("#mydiscouttext").style.display = "none";
}
```

this can be help

Answer (score 0):

there, in plain Javascript,

```js
var discount = document.getElementById('ammount').innerHTML;
console.log(discount);
if(parseInt(discount) <= 0 ) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('discount_discountAmount')[0].classList.add("hide");
}
```

```html
<div class="discount_discountAmount">
    <div id="mydiscouttext" class="discouttext"><span id="ammount">0</span>
        <span class="price_percent">%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, i added a span to isolate the percentage amount. it's easy to deal with it then.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to put it inside a span like the percent and try to put make a javascript like this

```
<div>
<span id="mydiscouttext">0</span>
<span>%</span>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function(){

var text = $("#mydiscouttext").html();

if(text == "0")
 $("#mydiscouttext").hide();


});

</script>
```

Comment: `html()` will give you `0
        <span class="price_percent">%</span>`

Comment: you're not hiding % sign in that suggestion too

Comment: then hide the div, replace the `$("#mydiscouttext").hide();` with `$("#discount_discountAmount").hide();` and we are just giving you the idea of how to do it not do it all for you